# RHEL Atomic Host 7 OpenShift Enterprise installation

Tags: atomic, host, rhel, openshift-enterprise

Good, installation [instruction](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/openshift-container-platform/3.3/single/installation-and-configuration#overview)

describes installation for RHEL 7 (rpm and containerized) and RHEL 7 Atomic Host 7 (containerized only), rpm seems to be valid. But how to use Atomic Host, there are no clear instructions?
Even:

```
-bash-4.2# atomic host install atomic-openshift-utils

Downloading metadata:     [==================================================] 100%
Resolving dependencies... done
Checking out tree 90c9735... done
error: Package 'openshift-ansible-playbooks' has (currently) unsupported script of type '%pretrans'
```

don't help.

Answer (score 1):

atomic host install supports only a subset of the available rpms packages.  More in detail, rpm without scripts (pretrans in your case) are supported.

You can install atomic-openshift-utils on a regular RHEL machine and do the installation from there.